# How to import all model in package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2.
I am making some packages for my project.

In App there are some models already define and using them in application.
In Package that I am creating I want to use that models, I am right now using them by importing individually like

```
use App\User;
use App\Group;
...
```

So for every different model I have to import individually, is there any way using which I can import all models. So that I don't have to add them individually.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, no, you can't do it with PHP as it currently stands. It has nothing to do with Laravel, but with php internals and language design.

**PHP 7** brings the possibility of [grouping namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php), so you can do something like:

```
use App\{User, Group, OtherClass};
```

instead of listing each `use` statement on its own line, but using *wildcards* is, so far, still un unfulfilled request.

On his blog post, Dayle Rees suggests a clever trick for going around this limitation (here: http://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained/), that is using a "parent" namespace and instantiate the child classes from it.

Taken right from the linked page:

```
use Dayle\Blog as Cms;

$post = new Cms\Content\Post;
$page = new Cms\Content\Page;
$tag  = new Cms\Tag;
```

This is still far from the benefits that a wildcard matching would have, but can be of your liking.